# How to capture Exception and use as a normal variable?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, variables, exception, error-handling

```
try:
   a = 1/0
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

For example, I would like to store the exception into a variable named "Error Log" insert insert the variable into a SQLite table?

Comment: Just assign e to your variable.

Comment: Somehow I missed that, thanks!

Comment: `e` is out of scope once you leave the `except` block. Try `print(x)`.